# Angular translate doesn't translate dynamic variable

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Angular translate doesn't translate dynamic variables. I have row

```
"TRANSLATION_ID": "{{username}} is logged in.",
```

in the translations file and

```
$translate('TRANSLATION_ID', { username: 'PascalPrecht' }).then(function (foo) {
    console.log(foo);
});
```

in controller, but it prints this to console:

```
 is logged in.
```

Why is it not adding the provided username to the translation?

Comment: does $translate.instant('TRANSLATION_ID', { username: 'PascalPrecht' }) have the same issue?

Comment: Tried it, yes it still only prints the part without the variable.

Comment: Variable replacement works with $translate service. Can you please check your console for error messages? check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/UfcizTOHzrWGLIInm0LK?p=preview

Comment: No errors in console, and only "What an awesome module!" appears on the html. Oh well I give up